# Find lines that contain given word and return in array

Tags: php

Lets say I have following lines:

```
How, are you!
Are you there?
Yes, you over there.
```

I have to display those lines which contains word "there", In my case it should return following array of strings:

```
["Are you there?", "Yes, you over there."]
```

What I did is :

```
$arr = array();
        while (!feof($file)) {
            $line = fgets($file);
            if (strpos($line, $keyword) !== false) {
                $arr[]=$line;
            }
        }
        print_r($arr);
        return;
```

How can I get the result in `["Are you there?", "Yes, you over there."]` format.

Comment: what's a problem with this code?

Comment: I am trying this question for test dome for which I am getting wrong answer.

Comment: Did you give up or what???

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way:

```
$result = preg_grep("/$keyword/", file("/path/to/file.txt"));
```

- `file()` creates an array of each line
- grep over the array for the keyword

If you want that literal string, then that is JSON:

```
$string = json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex?

```
 preg_match_all("/.* there .*|there .*|.* there.*/", $input_str, $output_array);
```

You can replace the "there" with a variable.

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fLn